# iPhone memory warning for high resolution images

Tags: iphone

I have an app which display images in full Screen. Some of the images are 1952x3680 pixels and these images are raising memory warning level=1 and level=2.

How should i handle these image?

Comment: Why all the down votes? I'm sure this question will be helpful to anyone else looking to do something similar especially since they would not be able to scale these images down within the app itself.

Comment: I agree.  The question doesn't necessarily deserve down votes.  I'm looking for a solution to a similar problem, and the question as worded attracted my attention.  It's too bad so many Pharisees run around SO these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use them. Either get your server to deliver a thumbnail version of the image (maybe using a `thumb.php`/`jsp`/`asp`/`...` file with GET params `x=<width>&y=<height>`), or scale the image down on the iPhone and *discard* the original data. The former method is vastly preferred as it saves on both bandwidth and large memory allocations client-side.

The largest images you should be working with are 480x320 (iPhone 3GS and earlier) and 960x640 (iPhone 4).

*EDIT:* The other situation I didn't think of is if you're bundling these images with the app. Please, please don't do that. If you have images that big, scale them down in Apple's `Preview` or any image editor to the sizes noted, and ideally have two copies, `image.png` and `image@2x.png` which are shown depending on the `scale` of the device's screen.

Comment: Agreed that the images should be scaled-down before they ever make it to the device. Just look at other apps out on the app store that do this (i.e. Facebook). There are usually several sizes/types for the same image such as a special thumbnail (to show in a gallery view) and different sizes of the image itself to allow flexibility in quality, bandwidth and device limitations. Doing this on the server-side would be the most beneficial.

Answer (score 4):

Scale your images down considerably. There is absolutely no reason you need images at that resolution in an iPhone app.

Answer (score 3):

The screen itself is only 320x460 (not considering the clock bar on top), and 640x960 for retina display. There is no reason to have images this large to begin with. Scale them down. It'll both prevent the memory warnings and stymie unnecessary image size.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, scale it down if you only want to show the image without zooming in fullscreen. 
If you need to zoom and show it detailed, google for CATiledLayer. There are good examples around.